# Why are Java Strings allocated memory on heap?

Tags: java, string, memory, heap-memory

In Java, why are `String` datatypes allocated memory on the heap?

Comment: What is that code block demonstrating?

Comment: What else do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is simple all objects are stored on the heap. It is designed like that. String is a class and its object will be stored on the heap.

Also note that `String` literals were previously stored in a Heap called the "permgen" heap. Now according to the JVM Specification, the area for storing string literals is in the **runtime constant pool**.

Only the primitive datatypes are stored on stack.

> Heap memory is used by java runtime to allocate memory to Objects and
> JRE classes. Whenever we create any object, it’s always created in the
> Heap space. Garbage Collection runs on the heap memory to free the
> memory used by objects that doesn’t have any reference. Any object
> created in the heap space has global access and can be referenced from
> anywhere of the application.

A good point to [quote from the JDK7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html#jdk7changes)

> Area: HotSpot
>
> Synopsis: In JDK 7, interned strings are no longer
> allocated in the permanent generation of the Java heap, but are
> instead allocated in the main part of the Java heap (known as the
> young and old generations), along with the other objects created by
> the application. This change will result in more data residing in the
> main Java heap, and less data in the permanent generation, and thus
> may require heap sizes to be adjusted. Most applications will see only
> relatively small differences in heap usage due to this change, but
> larger applications that load many classes or make heavy use of the
> String.intern() method will see more significant differences. RFE:
> 6962931

Answer (score 0):

By default all objects are on the heap.  String has two objects, the `String` and the `char[]` it wraps.  It is not unusual to find the most numerous object by type is a `char[]` even if you create none directly.

What is surprising is that it doesn't always create objects on the heap, but it can place objects on the stack through escape analysis.  Note: it can't do this for String literals as they are stored in the String literal pool.

Answer (score 0):

When user enters the Strings, its always dynamic that is the size of the string may change for each execution, hence the compiler doesn't know the exact memory requirement needed for the String. Even during the run time, the size of string is not predicted until the user enters the complete string, so no memory can be assigned on the stack, hence, it generally stores a pointer on the stack which points to the string (on the heap).